# Changing system time on MySQL server

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

I've discovered that my MySQL server is 10 minutes behind the current time because NTP was not running for some reason.

It is a single node and running MySQL version 5.6.15-56.

I know that changing time can affect replication in clusters but does it have any effect on single node servers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe none of these matter, but here are some guesses:

- Strange values in the data (in your application) due to 10 minute jump.
- Out of order things if you need to back up 10 minutes.  Search your code for `ORDER BY`.  (Other constructs could be affected, too.)
- cron jobs and MySQL Events that fail to run or run twice.  (If you have trouble here, re-code them to protect themselves.)

There are probably more things, but I can't think of any 'dangerous' ones.

Comment: Were any of these 'guesses' the 'right' answer for you?  Or did you discover something else?